# Linked list without malloc

Tags: c, malloc, undefined-behavior, singly-linked-list, storage-duration

I'm starting to learn C myself, and based on the book "Programming in C (4th Edition)", the author defined a linked list as following:

```
struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

struct entry *createNewLinkList(void)
{
    struct entry n1, n2, n3;
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = NULL;
    return list_pointer;
}

void print_linked_list(struct entry *linked_list)
{
    struct entry *current = linked_list;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct entry *linked_list = createNewLinkList(); //DEBUG: This line is fine linked_list: {value:100, next:0x000000016fdff200}
    printf("Original list \n");
    print_linked_list(linked_list);   //DEBUG: it is wrong after entering this line linked_list:{value:1876947504, next:0x8b7a000100003f48}
}
```

I don't understand why the value of `linked_list` just changed to some address.

Is will work if I create a linked list with malloc like this:

```
struct entry *createNewLinkList(void)
{
    struct entry *n1 = (struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    struct entry *n2 = (struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    struct entry *n3 = (struct entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));

    n1->value = 100;
    n1->next = n2;

    n2->value = 200;
    n2->next = n3;

    n3->value = 300;
    n3->next = NULL;
    return n1;
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is the first code sample from the book? Because it seems to me like some local variables are defined in the function createNewLinkList() but their scope will end, so by the time you use the pointer returned by this function in the main() function, you no longer have the guarantee that the data is still at that location in memory.

Comment: I hope you copied the example wrong from the book... otherwise, for the love of God just throw it in the trash now :')

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it valid code, you could make the nodes static:  `static struct entry n1, n2, n3;` But with that change, you will not be flexible at all and only ever use these 3 nodes.

Comment: If this example is actually verbatim from the book, burn the book.

Comment: The only purpose that code serves is to illustrate undefined behavior in a program.  It contains mistakes I wouldn't even expect a beginner to make.  The pointer it returns is invalid, and the list nodes will most likely be overwritten as soon as another function call is made.

Comment: The sample from the book but I try to reactory the code by create the linked list in a function and return the first pointer. That why it does not work. My bad still a noob. I think it already clear why it not working. Thanks !

Comment: In the book, the original version isn't written inside a separate function but in main().

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Even in good books there are mistakes in program examples.:)

Comment: (The book probably belongs in the trash anyway though, because in the next chapter he teaches how to call functions by declaring function prototypes inside main().)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow agree, usually not of this magnitude though.

Comment: I just had a glance at the book. IMHO it is definitely crap.

Comment: @Jabberwocky any suggestion for a better books or sources. I think the book is missing some explaination for beginners like me.

Comment: @AnhDucNguyen maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program in the book (if it is indeed the code from the book) has undefined behavior.

The function `createNewLinkList` returns a pointer to a local object with automatic storage duration (`n1`) that will not be alive (along with other local variables that are chained through pointers) after exiting the function

```
struct entry *createNewLinkList(void)
{
    struct entry n1, n2, n3;
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = NULL;
    return list_pointer;
}
```

So dereferencing the pointer (and other pointers stored in the data member `next` of the structure) within the function `print_linked_list`

```
void print_linked_list(struct entry *linked_list)
{
    struct entry *current = linked_list;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

invokes undefined behavior.

The program could be correct if the variables `n1`, `n2`, `n3` had static storage duration that is if they would be declared like

```
static struct entry n1, n2, n3;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaination, my beginning mistake ;)

Comment: @AnhDucNguyen No at all. We, beginners, should help each other.:)